# Laravel - Update All Rows With Prefix In The Value

Tags: database, laravel

[image]

For every row, I want to add prefix `cp_`...

But I don't know what is the correct and clean way in Laravel 5.6.

If I use the code below, it will update all rows with the same value.
I dont want that, I just want to add prefix with current value.

`DB::table($table_name)->update('slug_name','cp_'.$what_the_fish_to_put_here);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
DB::table(table_name)->update(['slug_name' => DB::raw('CONCAT("cp_", table_name.slug_name)')])
```

Comment: this code is working `DB::table($tableName)->update(['slug_name' => DB::raw("CONCAT('cp_', \`slug_name\`)")]);` .... Thanks!